# onChange and onSelectedIndexChanged events not firing - selectbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, onchange, drop-down-menu

I was able to implement the selectbox but onchange and OnSelectedIndexChanged are not firing. Any insights?

```
<div class="hasJS">
<asp:DropDownList class="custom" ID="myid" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="change" OnTextChanged="change" onChange="myChange();">
<asp:ListItem>Hello</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Hello1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Hello3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Hello4</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Hello5</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Hello6</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Hello7</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Hello8</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

   $(function () {

       $("select.custom").each(function () {
           var sb = new SelectBox({
               selectbox: $(this),
               height: 150,
               width: 200
           });
       });

   });

   function myChange() {
       alert("Hai");
   }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

set autopostback=true for DropDownList ;

```
<asp:DropDownList class="custom" autopostback="true" ID="myid" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="change" OnTextChanged="change" onChange="myChange();">
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help!

Answer (score 0):

*for the case of onChange add return to the javascript call*

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="cbProduct" runat="server" 
                                        CssClass="common_transaction_textbox_style" onchange="return LoadProductBatchByName();" Height="23px" Width="200px">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>

 function LoadProductBatchByName() {
{
          alert('test');
}
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help!

Comment: i have edited my code and changed onChange to onchange..!! it will work just check..!!

Answer (score 0):

i just copied your code and guess what it was working fine with AutoPostBack="True",first it shows alert message then twice event was getting fired for both event.i guess you must have implemented below snippet in your code behind file.

```
protected void change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```