# OnSelectedIndexChanged not firing once deployed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I'm not the first to complain about OnSelectedIndexChanged not firing in IE, once deployed:

- [OnSelectedIndexChanged not firing in production - IE 11 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666994/onselectedindexchanged-not-firing-in-production-ie-11-only)
- [DropDownList not firing OnSelectedIndexChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423227/dropdownlist-not-firing-onselectedindexchanged)
- [ASP.Net DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChange not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173124/asp-net-dropdownlist-onselectedindexchange-not-firing?rq=1)
- [onChange and onSelectedIndexChanged events not firing - selectbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928665/onchange-and-onselectedindexchanged-events-not-firing-selectbox?rq=1)
- And many more.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="MyDropDownList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Life" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Universe" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Everything" Value="42" />
</asp:DropDownList >
```

and:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    MyDropDownList.AutoPostBack = true;
    MyDropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(MyDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

protected void MyDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //lots of cool stuff
}
```

**Now let us dig into the result HTML**.

Here's with Chrome, (or IE with compatibility mode):

```
<select name="MyDropDownList" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(...)', 0)" id="MyDropDownList">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Life</option>
    <option value="2">Universe</option>
    <option value="42">Everything</option>
</select>
```

And here it is with IE10/IE11 (without compatibility):

```
<select name="MyDropDownList" id="MyDropDownList">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Life</option>
    <option value="2">Universe</option>
    <option value="42">Everything</option>
</select>
```

Surprise!
The `onchange` attribute is **gone**!

OK...
So now I know why the event isn't firing from IE.
...But why is it rendered differently?

Important detail: This only happens once deployed to server (I believe it's IIS6). Locally, it works fine.

Another important detail: Installing any sort of patch is unfortunately not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a known issue, with fixes:
[Scott Hanselman - bug in the browser definition files](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

> There is a bug in the browser definition files that shipped with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4, namely that they contain definitions for a certain range of browser versions. But the versions for some browsers (like IE 10) aren't within those ranges any more. Therefore, ASP.NET sees them as unknown browsers and defaults to a down-level definition, which has certain inconveniences, like that it does not support features like JavaScript.

The fixes are either
1. Update server's .NET (good idea)
2. Add appropriate `ie.browser` (can be found [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417420/app-browsers-definition-file-for-ie-11)) to `App_browsers` folder (workaround in case first option isn't available.)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do this :

```
<asp:DropDownList id="MyDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onSelectedIndexChanged="MyDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged"   >
<asp:ListItem Text="Life" Value="1" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Universe" Value="2" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Everything" Value="42" />
</asp:DropDownList >
```

and on server side :

```
protected void MyDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Truth is, I just posted my code as-is.  Your code IS cleaner, but doesn't solve the problem. Do you think I should neaten it up HERE, just to make it more readable?

Comment: i mean why you are adjusting an event handler from the code behind using the onInit and you have the ability to do it from the client side ? maybe the onInit function defer from IE and Firefox

Comment: OnInit happens on the server. Why would it be different for different browsers?